# Why does qt report: There is no disk in the drive. Please Insert a disk in to \Device\Harddisk4\DR4?

Tags: qt, windows-7, msys2

Qt reports

```
There is no disk in the drive. Please Insert a disk in to \Device\Harddisk4\DR4
```

during application startup.  Other posts have reported this is caused by accessing missing removable drives, but in my case, I didn't have any.  I wasn't calling QFileInfo().isreadable(), either.  This was with an MSYS2 build of Qt 5.11.

Using procmon I was able to see that the last file access was to the current folder for a file `qt.conf`.  Placing this file in the current folder was enough to get rid of the issue.

Previous versions of Qt did not exhibit this behavior.  This workaround isn't so bad, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to a newer build of Qt 5.11 in msys2, the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html

> Without qt.conf, the Qt libraries will use the hard-coded paths to
>   look for plugins, translations, and so on. These paths may not exist
>   on the target system, or they may not be accessible. Because of this,
>   you may need qt.conf to make the Qt libraries look elsewhere.

This is not a solution but it suggests the build may be looking for plugins in a hardcoded path.